# Python Class does not works properly "name error"

Tags: python-3.x, class

Hello I have a very simple class and python gives me a name error using Geany for editing
here is a screenshot
[image]

Comment: Along with the answer,. please also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to do
`print(str(self.question))`

Comment: you're welcome :-), you could mark it as an answer if it solves your problem. For the sake of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

question is attribute of the class. To access it, use self.question.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if it worked and solved your issue.